# Count appearances of foreign key

Tags: sql

Here are my tables:

```
class ( id:int , name:string , capacity:int)

student (id:int , name:string , class_id: foreign key to class)
```

I wanna update capacity and reduce it by the number of students with the same class id.How should I count it by UPDATE query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most databases the syntax is this:

```
update class
set capacity = capacity - (select count(*) from student where class_id = class.id)
```